# combining two select statements with GROUP and JOIN mysql

Tags: join, union

Hope someone can help.

I have two mysql select statements that each work, but I now need to combine them.

**First:**

```
SELECT $shares.*, $shares_company.name AS name, SUM($shares.number) AS totalNumber, MAX(date) AS lastTransDate, $shares.timestamp AS lastUpdated FROM $shares 
INNER JOIN
$shares_company WHERE $shares_company.id = $shares.company_id GROUP   BY $shares.company_id
```

**Second:**

```
SELECT $shares.price AS lastPrice 
FROM $shares WHERE ($shares.company_id,$shares.date) IN 
(SELECT $shares.company_id, MAX($shares.date) FROM $shares GROUP BY $shares.company_id)
```

I tried `UNION` and `UNION ALL`, and all sorts of other combinations.

I am stuck!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRjPY.png)

**UPDATE:**

Well, that's how far I now got. This returns all the correct info except that I need to get the sum of the 'number' column and I don't know where to insert that into the query.
The query to insert is:

```
SELECT
SUM($shares.number) AS totalNumber FROM $shares 
GROUP BY $shares.company_id
```

The query I now have is:

```
SELECT $shares.price AS lastPrice,
$shares.date AS lastTransDate, 
$shares.company_id,
$shares.id,
$shares.timestamp AS lastUpdated,
$shares_company.name
FROM $shares 

INNER JOIN $shares_company
ON $shares_company.id = $shares.company_id

WHERE ($shares.company_id,$shares.date) IN 
(SELECT $shares.company_id, MAX($shares.date)
FROM $shares
GROUP BY $shares.company_id)
```

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: u cant use union if number of field is different. try to use left join.

Comment: I put 'LEFT JOIN' in between the two statements, but no joy.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the lastPrice result within the first query. In that case, I'd try something like this:

```
SELECT
  $shares.*,
  $shares_company.name AS name,
  SUM($shares.number) AS totalNumber,
  MAX(date) AS lastTransDate,
  $shares.timestamp AS lastUpdated FROM $shares,
  ( SELECT $s.price
    FROM $shares AS $s
    WHERE $s.company_id = $shares.company_id
    ORDER BY $s.date DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS lastPrice
  INNER JOIN $shares_company
    ON $shares_company.id = $shares.company_id
GROUP BY $shares.company_id
```

(Note: this is untested, but the reasoning should be clear: create an inner query to select the last share price for this given row, then return it as another column).

Comment: Thank you for your efford, however doesn't quite work. I made some changes to your query, but still no luck. The 'lastPrice' that gets returned is the first result not, as it should be, the result that relates to the row with the most recent 'lastUpdated'. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Does it work if you change $s.date to $s.lastUpdated in my query?

Comment: Sorry does not work. if I modify your query I get the correct results except for the Last Price Paid.

SELECT
  $shares.*,
  $shares_company.name AS name,
  SUM($shares.number) AS totalNumber,
  MAX(date) AS lastTransDate,
  $shares.company_id,
  $shares.price AS lastPrice,
  $shares.timestamp AS lastUpdated 
  FROM $shares,
  ( SELECT $shares.price
    FROM $shares
    WHERE $shares.id = $shares.company_id
    ORDER BY $shares.date DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS test
  INNER JOIN $shares_company
    WHERE $shares_company.id = $shares.company_id
GROUP BY $shares.company_id

Comment: That's not my query - I refer to $shares as $s within the inner query to avoid alias overlap. I suppose it makes little difference, but I can take another look at this later tonight.